How do I get my Keras Tuner to train for 10 epochs?
I have the following section of code:
tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective=['val_accuracy','val_loss'],
                     max_epochs=10,
                     factor=20,
                     directory='my_dir',
                     project_name='intro_to_kt')

I know the formula is 1+logfactor(max_epochs).
I thought then to change it to this:
tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective=['val_accuracy','val_loss'],
                     max_epochs=3**9,
                     factor=3,
                     directory='my_dir',

But this trained it for one epoch per trial. Is there something that I am missing from the docs? I need my tuner to train the model for at 10 epochs before going to next trial.
My thought behind it was because log base 3 of 3 to nine is nine so nine plus 1 equals 10 giving me 10 epochs.

In hyperband the max epochs should be 'integer'.you can not give max epochs=1 + logfactor(max_epochs).Because of the following reason
The Hyperband tuning algorithm uses adaptive resource allocation and early-
stopping to quickly converge on a high-performing model.  The algorithm
trains a large number of models for a few epochs and carries forward only the
top-performing half of models to the next round. Hyperband determines the
number of models to train in a bracket by computing '1 + logfactor(max_epochs)'
and rounding it up to the nearest integer.
